# Navigation Drawer library what does fragmentmain mean

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

So I'm using  [this library](https://github.com/rudsonlive/NavigationDrawer-MaterialDesign) to make a navigation drawer but one thing is not explained:

In the OnItemClick function:

```
public void onItemClick(int position) {
    FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment mFragment = new FragmentMain().newInstance(mHelpLiveo.get(position).getName());

    if (mFragment != null){
        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, mFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

It tells me that FragmentMain is unresolved. I don't know what it means. Do I have to create a new Fragment in MainActivity??

Answer (score 0):

You provided the example code from the library description. This code part is shown as example of implementing OnItemClick listener. In your case it seems that you copy-pasted this part and, apparently, you don't have such a fragment as FragmentMain. In order to implement  the navigation,  menu position can be used to  handle actions related to menu items.

In this particular case, I suppose, after clicking on menu item with specified position fragment manager use newly created fragment with some name which stored in mHelpLiveo list and stored by index related to menu position.

Anyway, you have to implement your own behavior of OnItemClick listener.  Let's consider scenario you have menu:

- Home
- Weather
- etc

In this case, if you have different fragments for different pages  onItemClick method would have following code:

```
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    Fragment fragment;
    switch(position):{
        case 0: fragment = HomeFragment.newInstance(); break;
        case 1: fragment = WeatherFragment.newInstance(); break;
        case 2: fragment = EtcFragment.newInstance; break;
        default: fragment = HomeFragment.newInstance(); break;
    }


    if (fragment != null){
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code like this

Replace Fragment object by FragmentMain while creating new instance

Also I think the new Instance is static method.So you can access it directly using class name.

```
public void onItemClick(int position){

    FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentMain mFragment =  FragmentMain.newInstance(mHelpLiveo.get(position).getName());
    if (mFragment != null){
        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, mFragment).commit();
    }
}
```